# setting up local time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I live in timezone GMT+5.30. My rails application while saving the values for updated_at and created_at always saves the GMT time. How can i default my rails application to enter the time in GMT+5.30 time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a while to catch this one too ...

in your environement.rb file, there is a :

```
config.time_zone = "something"
```

change it to :

```
config.time_zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
```

for example, and the time displayed in your views will be automatically converted.

Rails just stores time like this by default.  it is you locale that convert the time to the good timezone.

Comment: Its actually in the application.rb file.

Comment: You are prob. right, i checked in my old project which was rails 2.3.2. they prob. moved it in the application.rb.  Thanks for the update

Answer (score 2):

You should always store times in UTC in your database so that it is not geographically bound. You can then present the times in the user's local time, or a system default of whatever you want. to do that modify the following in your application_controller.rb For instance:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_user_time_zone

protected
  def set_user_time_zone
    Time.zone = 'New Delhi'
  end
end
```

You can render all these times in local time:

```
Time.now.localtime.in_time_zone(Time.zone)
# => Thu, 25 Aug 2011 01:23:43 IST +05:30
```

You could probably clean that up with a helper method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will get your answer here providing you app is on Rails 3.